# How to remove duplicate lines from text file having more than 200K rows and its size is 1 GB?

Tags: c#, file, csv, file-io

Presently i am using following code......its working for only 300 lines of text file..and it will take 2minits to execute this program code... but my text file is having more than 200k of rows(lines), so this code is not working for that file...so plz anyone help me to solve this problem...thanks in advance..

```
string[] source = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Documents and Settings\finaloutput.txt");      

var q1 = (from line in source
          let fields = line.Split(',')
          select new
          {
              autoid = fields[0],
              ATMID = fields[4],
              DATE = fields[2],
              TIME = fields[3],
              CARDNo = fields[5],
              TRANSId = fields[6],
              SEQNo = fields[7],
              TRANSIT = fields[8],
              CheckNo = fields[9],
              CATEGORY = fields[10],
              SCORE = fields[11],
              //THRESHOLD = fields[12]
          });


    var ids = (from d in q1
               where d.CATEGORY != "Accepted"
               group d by new { d.ATMID, d.DATE, d.CARDNo, d.TRANSIT, d.CheckNo } into grp
               select grp.Min(x => x.autoid));


    var toDelete = (from d in q1
                    where !ids.Contains(d.autoid) && d.CATEGORY != "Accepted"
                    select d.autoid);

    // source1.DeleteOnSubmit(toDelete);

    var distinct = (from d in q1
                    where !toDelete.Contains(d.autoid)
                    select d);



    // Makes a list of the DeletedFields  
    // var list_Of_CSV_ItemsDeleted = distinct.Select(x => string.Join(",", x.autoid));

    // Makes a list of the distinct Fields  
    var list_Of_CSV_ItemsDistinct = distinct.Select(x => string.Join(",", x.autoid, x.ATMID, x.DATE, x.TIME, x.CARDNo, x.TRANSId, x.SEQNo, x.TRANSIT, x.CheckNo, x.CATEGORY, x.SCORE)); 
    System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Documents and Settings\distict1.txt", list_Of_CSV_ItemsDistinct);
```

Comment: What is "2 lacs of rows(lines)"?  I assume it's a big number.

Comment: @DanPichelman a `lac` is 100K.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud - that's a new one to me.  Thanks

Comment: Apparently: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh

Comment: Lac is only used in Asia, generally about money.  Not sure it fits in a question on Stack Overflow...

Comment: Processing a 300 line CSV in 2 minutes is reason to suspect less than optimal performance unless you're on a very old processor.  It might be useful to write a version without Linq for comparison.  I'm not slamming Linq (I like it), but question whether it's the right tool for this job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to rewrite this for you, but one thing you're going to need to do is leverage deferred execution. Consider this code:

```
var enumerable = File.ReadLines(filePath);
```

This returns an `IEnumerable<string>`, so it only reads a line from the file when you ask for one. Now consider this code:

```
var next100 = enumerable.Take(100);
```

That would take 100 lines and let you work with them. This is how you're going to have to do it. You could still use those same LINQ queries almost, but only a section at a time.

So, instead of something like this:

```
var q1 = (from line in source ...
```

it might have to be something like this:

```
var q1 = (from line in source.Take(100) ...
```

Comment: ReadAllLines does **not** defer execution.  Perhaps you meant to write `ReadLines` instead?

Comment: @Servy, yes that's what I meant. Thanks a lot, I'll edit, and great catch!

Comment: @Michael Perrenoud, yes its working fine, but it is giving the result for 100 lines, what about rest of the lines, how it will going to take next 100 lines....can you plz write the code for this...thanks.

Comment: @user, you'll need an outer loop that runs until there are no more lines returned from the ReadLines.